When is a multivariate Bernoulli Markov chain with transition $\mathcal{B}(\textbf{X}_{t}; \textbf{X}_{t-1}(1-\beta_t)+0.5\beta_t)$ reversible?
My question arises from Wang et. al.
Setup:
We have a sequence $\textbf{X}_0, \dots, \textbf{X}_T$ random variables in a multivariate binary space, that is $\textbf{X}_i = \textbf{x}$ with $\textbf{x}\in\{0,1\}^d$, i.e. $\textbf{x}$ is a binary vector of dimension $d$. Such sequence is a Markov chain given by the transition kernel
$$ q(\textbf{X}_t | \textbf{X}_{t-1}) = \mathcal{B}(\textbf{X}_{t}; \textbf{X}_{t-1}(1-\beta_t)+0.5\beta_t), $$
where $\\{\beta_t\\}\_{t=1}^T$ is called the noise schedule, and $\beta_t \in (0,1)$, for all $t$. Here $\beta_t$'s and $T$ are chosen so that
$$q(\textbf{X}_{T} | \textbf{X}_{0}) \approx \mathcal{B}(\textbf{Y}; 0.5).$$
When applying the above transitions enough times, the information that one has at $t=0$ gets destroyed by the noise addition.
Goal:
One would like to be able to recover the noised information from $\textbf{x}_{T}$ back to $\textbf{x}_{0}$. To do so, in the paper they train a Neural Network to learn the reverse step $q(\textbf{X}_{t-1} | \textbf{X}_{t})$.
Problem:
For this to work first we need to prove that the Markov chain is actually reversible, and that the reverse transitions are given by another multivariate Bernoulli. Then the NN will be trained to learn the parameters of the reverse Bernoulli.
Okay, let's see if it is invertible. What I tried is the following. Focus on the $i$-th random variable $X_t^i$ from the vector $\textbf{X}_t$, ignore the $i$ to simplify notation. In this case we have that the transition matrix of $X_{t-1}$ to $X_t$ is
\begin{equation}
 Q_t = \begin{bmatrix} 1-0.5\beta_t & 0.5\beta_t \\\ 0.5\beta_t & 1-0.5\beta_t \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
Thefore,
$$ 
q(X_t = x_t | X_{t-1} = x_{t-1}) = v(x_{t})^T Q_t v(x_{t-1})
$$
where $v(x_{t}) = [1, 0]$ if $x_{t} = 0$, and $v(x_{t}) = [1, 0]$ if $x_{t} = 1$.
As far as I understand, judging from $Q_t$ this is an irreducible Markov chain with invariant distribution $\pi = [0.5, 0.5]$, since $\pi Q_t = \pi$ for any $t$. And, as far as I understand, it satisfies the definition of reversible Markov chains, since
$$ \pi_0 Q_{0,1} = \pi_1 Q_{1,0} $$
here $Q = Q_t$ for any $t$. Furthermore, the inverse transition matrix is given by
$$ \hat{Q}_{0,1} = \frac{\pi_1}{\pi_0} Q_{1,0} = Q_{1,0} $$
which leads to the inverse transition matrix
$$ \hat{Q}_t = Q_t $$
for any $t$.
Question: Can this reasoning be applied to the entire vector $\textbf{X}_t$ with a tensor $\textbf{Q}_t$ that collects all transition matrices? My guess is that yes. However, if that is the case, then wouldn't I be able to compute in a closed form the reverse transition $q(\textbf{X}_{t-1} | \textbf{X}_{t})$, making the need of learning a NN to approximate this step useless? What am I missing here?
Any advice or comment on this matter is very much welcome. Thank you in advance for taking your time.
